# Alternative to stroke-dashoffset?

Tags: svg

I am using stroke-dasharrays inside line tags in my SVG file for my cutting plotter to create fold lines.

However, if I use stroke-dashoffset to change where the strokes begin, the plotter can not read the file properly (The file preview is a mess of lines and when cutting it, it just ignores the fold lines).

Are there alternatives for stroke-dasharrays?

Comment: Which software are you using to generate the SVG file? Did you try converting the stroke to path?

Comment: Please try this: `<line  stroke-dasharray="0 10 5"`

Comment: @Mehdi I am using Notepad++.

Comment: @enxaneta I can't try that right now, but I will in a week. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Can you give an example of how you tried to adjust the dash offset?  What software are you using with your plotter?  Do you know what software it uses to preview the file?  There are really no alternatives for `stroke-dashoffset` - other than moving the start of your line obviously.  Your best bet would probably be to report the bug to the plotter software.

Answer (score 2):

One solution which may be of use is to run your SVG through Inkscape (free SVG editor).

It includes an extension that can convert a dashed line to a path consisting of a subpath for each dash segment.

- Load the SVG into Inkscape
- Adjust the dashoffset now if you haven't already ("Fill and Stroke" panel -> "Stroke style")
- Select the dashed line
- Select `Extensions -> Modify Path -> Convert to Dashes.
- Save the file.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Now your line has no dash pattern and your plotter software should be happy. Hopefully.

Comment: Hi, Inkscape always gives me the error message that inkex.debug is depricated. I have already changed it to inkex.utils.debug, but now it just says "Total number of objects not converted: 1
['line220']"
How do I fix this?

Comment: I've never seen this error. Are you running the latest Inkscape version?  I used 1.2.

Comment: Hello, I have tried your method on a diferent computer now. The same error message keeps appearing. I use Inkscape 1.2

Comment: @SchildiMrStuffcoBakob I don't know the solution. It might be better to ask on the Inkscape Forums, or file a bug.